# problem with axios get error 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, postman

I have been stuck for quite a while because when I launch a call to my API to retrieve data (therefore a GET method) I have a 400 bad request error off on postman I manage to retrieve the data in status 200. However in my axios I pass the parameters well as well as the useful headers.

Code axios status 400 :

```js
async getAssociatedPlant() {                
                this.$axios.$get('lnk/plant/plants', {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    params: {
                        link: "good",
                        plant_id: this.plantActive.id,
                    },
                    
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response) 
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    });
            },
```

Image useful for understanding :

[Postman Headers status 200 OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCiLJ.png)

[Postman Params status 200 OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVoKX.png)

[Erreur  400 bad request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaVA4.png)

[Request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDiBS.png)

[Request Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d63Fo.png)

Comment: You forgot to add 'api/...' in your route

Comment: No, it's present in my request (see image of the 400 bad request) it's the base_url of my api in the .env

Comment: can you please translate the Response in English

Comment: @PierroTH can you open chrome dev tools and show a picture of the request?

Comment: in the response, it is written: "this field is obligatory" for the two keys

Comment: yes @PierroTH so it means axios is not sending those fields to the server

Comment: Here picture of the request : https://ibb.co/bLG7v02

Comment: Try using localhost:8000 instead of the 127.0.0.1

Comment: This would potentially be for what? @Abdusalammohamed

Comment: Why are you claiming that the request body (which cannot exist because you are making a GET request) is a JSON text?

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed i test localhost always the error

Comment: @Quentin Because I took over someone's project and in their API even for GET methods there is a Content-Type

Comment: @PierroTH what is the content-type header on PostMan

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed is application/json too

Comment: how does your endpoint look like? is it Js or?

Comment: what do you mean by endpoint? @Abdusalammohamed

Comment: Your server's route

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed GET route is http://localhost:8000/api/lnk/plant/plants

Comment: try hard coding it like: `this.$axios.$get('lnk/plant/plants?link=good&plant_id=' + this.plantActive.id, {headers})`

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed I've tried and still the same, there's something that shouldn't work, but I don't understand what

Comment: try deleting the header and also the params only leave the request url

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed It always puts me error 400 bad request and in the preview I have link: this field is mandatory and plant_id: this field is mandatory 
Likewise for the response.
While with the params in the preview I have what I send in params but in the response I also have "this field is mandatory"

Comment: So the problem is not in your getAssociatedPlant method it is either the **End point** meaning the server that is handling the request or you need to make sure that this is the exact same server your postman is communicating with

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed I will watch this, thank you very much for your help and patience

Answer (score -2):

Try adding data:{} to your request config.

```
async getAssociatedPlant() {
    this.$axios.$get('lnk/plant/plants', {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data:{},
        params: {
            link: "good",
            plant_id: this.plantActive.id,
        },

    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: @Quentin If no data is sent, then Axios removes the content type from headers.
This github thread might explain this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86

Comment: @AdarshThakur I tested that does not work either ...

Comment: can you share a more detailed Screenshot of the request or cURL?

Comment: @AdarshThakur  https://ibb.co/bLG7v02 that’s not enought ?

Comment: where you able to fix it?